# Send/receive byte array to/from ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I have lots of very small video files stored as byte arrays in my Java program. I want to take screenshots of each of them using `ffmpeg` command line. One solution is to write each file on the disk and then invoke `ffmpeg` command via `ProcessBuilder` and then read the output image from the disk again. However this needs a lot of disk operations that could be eliminated if there is a way to send/receive byte arrays to/from `ffmpeg`.

I just want to know if it is possible to do it without writing data to disk.

Comment: why not pipe to stdin?

Comment: @szatmary how can I do it?